# How to integrate java apis with HTML pages

Tags: java, html, browser, jar, applet

I have a jar file which i want to integrate with web page and run on web browser (my be chrome). So what i want to do is calling a java API which will give me some data using which i want to populate web page. so the java code will run in the background. Now user can select any one of the option from web page and i want to send user input through java API.

Only thing i can think of currently is through java applet. Is there any other way to do this. May be something similar to applet already available in the market.

Comment: Forget about Java applets. They are obsolete and not supported in current versions of Java. The current way to do this is to write the client side code in JavaScript or TypeScript, and make that communicate with Java services running on a server.

Comment: I want to do this without running a server ...  running locally on the machine. is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, you can run a Java program that acts as a webserver on your own computer and use a browser to access it. No external server is necessary.